# android paypal in-app payment: failed to initialize paypal library

Tags: android, paypal

The following shows my code used to initialize a paypal object in my android app.
Runtime error is resulted from doInBackground() so i think it is probably due to false returned by payPal.isLibraryInitialized().

Do you guys have experience on paypal integration in android app?

```
private class PayPalInitializer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private static final String APP_ID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
    private Context mContext;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    public PayPalInitializer(Context context) {
      mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
      mProgressDialog.setMessage("...");
      mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
      boolean success = false;
      PayPal payPal = PayPal.getInstance();
      if (payPal == null) {
        payPal = PayPal.initWithAppID(mContext, APP_ID, PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);
        payPal.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);
        // Set to true if the transaction will require shipping.
        payPal.setShippingEnabled(true);
        if (payPal.isLibraryInitialized()) {
          success = true;
        }
      }
      return success;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      mProgressDialog.hide();
      mProgressDialog = null;
      if (result) {
        setupButton();
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: found "Could not find class 'com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalPayment', referenced from method ..." error before the doInBackground..what I included in my project is PayPal_MPL.jar downloaded from x.com...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of error occurs if you have added jar file but it is not included properly.Right click on your project and then go to properties--java build path--order and export.There check if checkbox beside the jar.It should be checked.run your app again and check if same issue exists.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forget to put this permission on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```